# Why a normal vector can be used for finding a radius vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

There is a tetrahedron in the first octant with vertices (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,2,0), (0,0,3).(0,0,0),(1,0,0),(0,2,0),(0,0,3).

This is the domain of the function
$f(x,y,z) = x^{1/2} + y^{1/2} + z^{1/2} + ( )^{1/2}$.
I need to find the last term.
[The solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvtF9.png)

The question is why I can use the normal vector for deriving radius vector? By my understanding, the normal vector can be used for determining the radius vector if they both have one direction. Please help

Comment: Are you asking why a plane perpendicular to $n$ is of the form $n\cdot x=d$?

Comment: The "solution" doesn't seem to follow from what proceeds it. Some context is missing, it seems. It is unclear what your actual question is here.

Comment: @Math1000 sorry maybe I confused you, the question is how from norm vector <6,3,2> I can get radius vector <1, 1/2, 1/3>?

Comment: @GregoryKovalchuk All the calculation does is decide to rescale so the $=6$ becomes an $=1$.

Comment: The solution mentions only a normal vector. I don't see any place where a "radius vector" is mentioned. Why are you asking about a radius vector?

Comment: @DavidK because r =x + y + z -> sphere equation

Comment: @J.G. but the normal vector is perpendicular to the plane and a radius vector is not.

Comment: $r=x+y+z$ is not a sphere equation. Even $r=x^{1/2} + y^{1/2} + z^{1/2}$ is not a sphere equation unless you say that $r$ is a constant. In the definition of $f(x,y,z),$ there is no constant. Honestly I think you are trying to see something in this problem that simply is not there.

Comment: @DavidK maybe, I just try to figure out with the solution.

Comment: The solution has nothing to do with spheres or radius vectors, so try looking at what it says.

Comment: My complaint about the solution is that the term inside the square root is determined only up to a positive constant factor. That is, if you did not divide by $6$ as the solution does, you still have a function with the specified domain. The answer could just as well be $6-6x-3y-2z.$